# Error while generating urn and authenticate code to view file

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

My first project with forge is just about finished but I am completely stuck on the last part. My app configures a part according to a json file.  And exports it as an stp. The download also works perfectly. But now I would like to receive an urn and the authenticate code.

I now receive an urn back and a authenticate code but something seems wrong. When I paste this in an html file that I found with an example where you only have to paste the urn and the authenticate code. Does he not show the model.

Can anyone see where my error is?

Below is the code I am using now

```
   public string GetTokenHeader()
    {
        if (Token.IsValid())
            return Token.GetHeader();

        var client = new RestClient(Url);

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("authentication/v1/authenticate", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("client_id", Key);
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", Secret);
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        request.AddParameter("scope", AuthScope);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ForgeToken>(response.Content);

     

        if (Token == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Call to get an Access token failed. Please check the enviroment variables FORGE_CLIENT_ID and/or FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET and also the configuration files for a proper end points.");
            return "";
        }

        if (!Token.IsValid())
            Console.WriteLine("Access token is not valid.\nThat usually means that enviroment variables FORGE_CLIENT_ID and/or FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET are not set properly.");


        return Token.GetHeader();
    }





   private static async Task<string> gettest(bool strFile)
    {
        ForgeRestResponse response = await s_ForgeDmClient.GetBucketObjectDetails(getOutputBucketKey(), s_Config.OutputPartLargeFile);


        string test = response.GetResponseContentProperty("objectId");


        //Console.WriteLine(response.GetType());
        //Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(response.IsSuccessStatusCode());
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes); ;

    }
```

Comment: I might be that I don't know Forge, but it's unclear to me what the problem is here. What does `Does he not show the model` mean? You also mention `...an html file that I found with an example...`. Do you have a link so we can see what that is about?

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you have successfully used the Forge Design Automation service to generate some kind of a STEP file, you have "downloaded" the file to a bucket in the Forge Data Management service, and now you're trying to view it using Forge Viewer, is that right?

Comment: If that's the case, it would be helpful to know what kind of web application you're trying to paste the URN and token into. Try setting up one of the sample apps (for example, https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-simple-viewer-dotnet) with the bucket that contains the STEP files.